# How to authorize domains for TinyCloud on iOS apps (built via Capacitor)

Tags: tinymce, capacitor

I've created an iOS app from my web app thanks to Capacitor and I'm having an issue with Tiny since the domain appears unapproved and I don't know how to fix it. On which domain runs a Capacitor app ? localhost ? capacitor ?

So my iOS users are seing the popup saying the domaine is not registered

[image]

Comment: Capacitor apps have `capacitor://localhost` (iOS) or `http://localhost (Android)` as their origin.

Comment: Yes but I could only add "capacitor" and "localhost" as approved domains. And it's not working :(

Comment: The origin is "capacitor://localhost" but I can't add that to my approved domains...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TinyMCE Cloud platform works with the `http` and `https` protocols but it won't accept non-standard protocols such as `capacitor`.

You could switch to bundling TinyMCE in your application as opposed to fetching it from our Cloud platform but there is currently no way to make our Cloud work with the `capacitor` protocol.

Comment: That's what I feared... Thanks